# Websphere to Tomcat migration: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/wsspi/uow/UOWActionException

Tags: java, tomcat8

I am migrating my application from webshpere to tomcate and IO getting below error while running tomcat server with web WAR file. PLease help me to solve this

```
INFO,DefaultListableBeanFactory,localhost-startStop-1] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@48a48ed: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,frameworkpum,commonProfileEntityManager,emCommon,centralCasServerURL,centralCasServerLoginURL,applicationServiceURL,casHttpsProxyHost,casHttpsProxyPort,casHttpsNonProxyHosts,proxyConfiguration,singleLogoutFilter,dciLogoutSuccessHandler,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,casAuthenticationFilter,casProcessingFilterEntryPoint,casAuthenticationProvider,serviceProperties,userService,dciscApp,propertiesHelper,facesHelper,accessDecisionManager,roleVoter,authenticatedVoter,accessDeniedHandler,syslogPath,auditManager,commonAuditService,auditConversionService,auditDTOToEntityConverter,auditEntityToDTOConverter,auditReportEntityToDTOConverter,auditDAO,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#1,auditpum,commonAuditEntityManager,emAudit,participantSearchDAO,intesSearchDAO,userProfileDAO,currencySearchDAO,countrySearchDAO,chargeTypeSearchDAO,commonMerchantCategoryDAO,contactSearchDAO,commonSecurityQuestionsDAO,applicationMakerCheckerManager,applicationManager,applicationService,commonDTOConverterService,userProfileManager,userProfileService,userProfileConversionFactory,menuBuilder,intesSearchManager,currencySearchManager,countrySearchManager,chargeTypeSearchManager,commonMerchantCategorySearchManager,participantSearchManager,contactSearchManager,intesSearchService,currencySearchService,countrySearchService,chargeTypeSearchService,commonMerchantCategorySearchService,participantSearchService,contactSearchService,commonSecurityQuestionsService,currencyConverter,countryConverter,intesConverter,chargeTypeConverter,commonMerchantCategoryConverter,participantConverter,participantCycleRangeConverter,contactConverter,commonSecurityQuestionsConverter,parser,securityHelper,passwordEncryptor,defaultPasswordGenerator,defaultPasswordValidator,passwordHelper,passwordManager,questionsHelper,questionsManager,racfAuthenticator,secApiWrapper,dsManagerWrapper,corporateLDAPConnectionParameters,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,makerCheckerIdFactoryImpl,makerBeanFactory,customNamespacePrefixMapper,annotationBasedCheckerService,serviceFactoryImpl,outstandingChangesServiceImpl,makerServiceImpl,checkerServiceProxy,makerCheckerDAOJpaImpl,makerCheckerEntityManager,makercheckerpum,emMakerChecker,makerCheckerManager,com.dcisc.common.makerchecker.XmlSerializer#0,applicationDatasource,emAer,aerEntityManager,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,aerClientDescTabDAO,aerFranchiseDescTabDAO,aerClientTabDAO,aerExceptionTabDAO,aerFranchiseTabDAO,grfSummarySearchService,grfExceptionSearchService,fileTranSearchService,grfSummarySearchManager,grfExceptionSearchManager,fileTranSearchManager]; root of factory hierarchy
[ERROR,ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/wsspi/uow/UOWActionException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWActionException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is throwed if you use the old spring `TransactionManager` configuration in `Tomcat`.
You have to replace `org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager` with another one.

Please refer [spring document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration) for more information. Since Tomcat does not offer all `Java EE` features. You may need other `TransactionManager` solution 
especially when your application access more than one database.